# Inline-block remove bottom space to add text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the below code to begin an animation for an acronym that makes the code transform to a vertical form. I'd like to have it where it will type the rest of the acronym out next to the letters on the button click. However doing so adds far to much space between all the type I want them to basically line up how they do before the button is pressed you can see what it currently does here:

```js
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
var c = 0;
var d = 0;
var e = 0;
var f = 0;
var balance = 'alance';
var execution = 'xecution';
var teamwork = 'eamwork';
var training = 'raining';
var experience = 'xperience';
var results = 'esults';
var speed = 50;

function typeWriter() {
  while (a < balance.length) {
    document.getElementById("balance").innerHTML += balance.charAt(a);
    a++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
  while (b < execution.length) {
    document.getElementById("execution").innerHTML += execution.charAt(b);
    b++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
  while (c < teamwork.length) {
    document.getElementById("teamwork").innerHTML += teamwork.charAt(c);
    c++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
  while (d < training.length) {
    document.getElementById("training").innerHTML += training.charAt(d);
    d++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
  while (e < experience.length) {
    document.getElementById("experience").innerHTML += experience.charAt(e);
    e++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
  while (f < results.length) {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += results.charAt(f);
    f++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}

function scroller() {
  var move = document.querySelectorAll(".move");
  var fade = document.querySelectorAll(".fade");

  for (var i = 0; i < move.length; i++) {
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var elementTop = move[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var elementVisible = 0;

    if (elementTop < windowHeight - elementVisible) {
      move[i].classList.add("active");
    } else {
      move[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < fade.length; i++) {
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var elementTop = fade[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var elementVisible = 0;

    if (elementTop < windowHeight - elementVisible) {
      fade[i].classList.add("active");
    } else {
      fade[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", scroller);
```

```css
.move {
  font-size: 105px;
  position: relative;
}

.move.active {
  font-size: 105px;
  position: relative;
  animation: mover 5s ease 0s normal forwards;
}

.fade {
  font-size: 105px;
  position: relative;
}

.fade.active {
  font-size: 105px;
  position: relative;
  animation: fader 2s ease 0s normal forwards;
}

.move.active span {
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: rotate 5s ease 0s normal forwards;
}

@keyframes mover {
  0.0% {
    transform: scale(1) translate(-0px, 0) skew(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) translate(-20%, 300px) skew(0deg) rotate(90deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0.0% {
    transform: scale(1) translate(-0px, 0) skew(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) translate(0px, 0px) skew(0deg) rotate(-90deg);
  }
}

@keyframes fader {
  0.0% {
    transform: scale(1) translate(-0px, 0) skew(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes typing {
  0% {
    width: 0%
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<CENTER>
  <h2 class="fade">IT'S </h2>
  <h2 class="move">
    <span id="balance">B</span>
    <span id="execution">E</span>
    <span id="teamwork">T</span>
    <span id="training">T</span>
    <span id="experience">E</span>
    <span id="results">R</span>
  </h2>
  <h2 class="fade">TOGETHER </h2>
</CENTER>

<button onclick="typeWriter()">Click me</button>
```

https://noahark.w3spaces.com/saved-from-Tryit-2022-04-29.html

Any and all help will be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your particular example, the spacing is coming from the lengths of the words. When I undo the rotation caused by the animation, we can see this:

[image: as the words rotate, they fill in the gaps]

So, if you *force* the length of the word to be one character (regardless of how many characters are actually there), then you no longer have the spacing problem caused by the words' length.

```css
.move span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.5ch;
}
```

[image: the words are aligned vertically with expected spacing]

---

Although forcing the span's width works, it can feel a little naughty. We're now relying on nice overflow behaviour, and hopefully we don't need the *true width* of the element for anything else.

I found that I didn't have to force width if we start at the *end* rather than the beginning. By default (no transform applied), it is already arranged as a column of words exactly like what you want at the end of the animation.

Then, you apply the 90 degree rotation to get the horizontal "BETTER" text. The animation *undoes* the rotation, meaning you always get what you expect at the end.

```js
const betterAcronym = document.querySelector('#better-acronym')
const revealButton = document.querySelector('#reveal-button')

const wait = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

const typeElement = async (element) => {
  const word = element.dataset['word']
  const start = element.textContent.length
  
  for (let c = start; c < word.length; ++c) {
    element.textContent += word[c]
    await wait(100)
  }
}

revealButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  betterAcronym.classList.add('revealed')
  
  await wait(2750) // length of the animation plus some
  
  Array.from(betterAcronym.children).forEach(typeElement)
})
```

```css
.acronym {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 0.5em 0.5em;
  transition: transform 2.5s ease-in-out;
}

.acronym > li {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: 0.5em 0.5em;
  transition: transform 2.5s ease-in-out;
}

.acronym.revealed {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.acronym.revealed > li {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

button {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
```

```html
<ol id="better-acronym" class="acronym">
  <li data-word="balance">B</li>
  <li data-word="execution">E</li>
  <li data-word="teamwork">T</li>
  <li data-word="training">T</li>
  <li data-word="experience">E</li>
  <li data-word="results">R</li>
</ol>
<button id="reveal-button">Reveal</button>
```

Comment: This is great but now with the together underneath it there is a huge amount of space due to the acronym. Example: https://prnt.sc/FvPDBYLlYS9c

Comment: Yes, you can use CSS to position and adjust everything to where you need it on screen. For example, Grid can make each row the same size. Here's a code pen to play around with to demonstrate that: https://codepen.io/auroratide/pen/MWQpMJN

Comment: Thank you very much you've been an extreme help now I just need it to play on scroll down. Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to provide `width: 73px` to `.move.active span`. And after the animation ends adjust the parent height.

 In the demo look for code comments. I've also fixed the typing effect code. View in full page mode.

```js
const move = document.querySelector(".move");
const fade = document.querySelectorAll(".fade");

const words = ['balance', 'execution', 'teamwork', 'training', 'experience', 'results'];
let col = 1;
let row = 0;
const speed = 100;

function typeWriter() {
   const e = document.getElementById(words[row]);
   e.textContent += words[row][col];
   col++;
   if(col >= words[row].length){
     col = 1;
     row++;
   }
   if(row < words.length)
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
   else
    typeWriter = () => console.log('can not rerun the animation');
}

function scroller() {
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var elementTop = move.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var elementVisible = 0;

    if (elementTop < windowHeight - elementVisible) {
      move.classList.add("active");
    } else {
      move.classList.remove("active");
    }

  for (var i = 0; i < fade.length; i++) {
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var elementTop = fade[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var elementVisible = 0;

    if (elementTop < windowHeight - elementVisible) {
      fade[i].classList.add("active");
    } else {
      fade[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
  }
}

// adjust parent height after the animation ends
// change the calculation as per your requirements
move.onanimationend  = (event)=>{
    if(move === event.target) {
      move.parentElement.style.height = move.parentElement.offsetHeight - move.offsetHeight + move.offsetWidth + - move.nextElementSibling.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", scroller);
```

```css
center{ border: 1px dashed gray;}
.move {
  font-size: 105px;
  position: relative;
}

.move.active {
  font-size: 105px;
  position: relative;
  animation: mover 5s ease 0s normal forwards;
  
  /* we need exact width to adjust the parent's height */
  width: fit-content;
}

.fade {
  font-size: 105px;
  position: relative;
}

.fade.active {
  font-size: 105px;
  position: relative;
  animation: fader 2s ease 0s normal forwards;
}

.move.active span {
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: rotate 5s ease 0s normal forwards;

  /* specify width equal to one character in the font */
  width: 73px;
}

@keyframes mover {
  0.0% {
    transform: scale(1) translate(-0px, 0) skew(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) translate(-20%, 300px) skew(0deg) rotate(90deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0.0% {
    transform: scale(1) translate(-0px, 0) skew(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) translate(0px, 0px) skew(0deg) rotate(-90deg);
  }
}

@keyframes fader {
  0.0% {
    transform: scale(1) translate(-0px, 0) skew(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes typing {
  0% {
    width: 0%
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%
  }
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<CENTER>
  <h2 class="fade">IT'S </h2>
  <h2 class="move">
    <span id="balance">B</span>
    <span id="execution">E</span>
    <span id="teamwork">T</span>
    <span id="training">T</span>
    <span id="experience">E</span>
    <span id="results">R</span>
  </h2>
  <h2 class="fade">TOGETHER </h2>
</CENTER>

<button onclick="typeWriter()">Click me</button>
```

Adjust the calculations as per your requirements.